# find ignores the first filename that I search for

Tags: linux, bash, find

I search for two files that has changed recently in a folder, but it seems I invoke `find` incorrectly. In return I get only the results for the second file.

`find /tmp -name 'twofirmscoop.so' -o -name 'twofirms.so' -exec ls -lt {} + 2>/dev/null`

Comment: When I just use `find /tmp -name 'twofirmscoop.so' -o -name 'twofirms.so'` it prints info about both files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-exec` argument only applies to the second match.  To group them, do:

```
find /tmp \( -name 'twofirmscoop.so' -o -name 'twofirms.so' \) -exec ls -lt {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find /tmp \( -name 'twofirmscoop.so' -o -name 'twofirms.so' \) -exec ls -lt {} + 2>/dev/null
```